# Find dangerous use of $_GET and $_POST with egrep

Tags: php, sql, regex, shell, grep

I would like to be sure, that I didn't use $_POST or $_GET in a way an attacker could make use of (XSS-Attacks, SQL-Injections). To find all lines where I used $_GET or $_POST I used this command:

```
egrep "_GET|_POST" -r -i MyFolder > dangerousUse.txt
```

dangerousUse.txt has 439 lines. If I search like this:

```
egrep "\$_GET|\$_POST" -r -i MyFolder > dangerousUse.txt
```

dangerousUse.txt has 0 lines. If I search like this:

```
egrep "_GET\[|_POST\[" -r -i MyFolder > dangerousUse.txt
```

dangerousUse.txt has 385 lines. I think this is the number I want, but I would like the $-sign to get matched, too.

My first question is: Why doesn't the second egrep-command work?

Now I am sure, that the input is used correct if one of the following commands have been applied:

- `mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($input))` or `mysql_real_escape_string ( htmlspecialchars ( $input ) )` or other combinations with whitespaces.
- `intval($input)`
- `isset($input)`
- `$input ==` or `== $input`

How can I find only those lines, where $_POST or $_GET are used without these functions? It would also be okay to delete the lines in dangerousUse.txt, where these functions are applied to each $_POST or $_GET in this line.

edit:

```
egrep '\$_GET\[|\$_POST\[' -r -i MyFolder > dangerousUse.txt
```

works, thanks to VGE for the first part of the answer. Now dangerousUse.txt has 385 lines. But the second one is more important for me.

for the second part, `egrep -v` inverts matches:

```
egrep '(isset|intval|mysql_real_escape_string\(htmlspecialchars|md5|datum_anpassen)[\w]*\(\$_' -i -v dangerousUse.txt > dangerousUse2.txt
```

Comment: I have added the shell tag because your question is related to the shell quoting and escaping.

Comment: What do you do when the value is written to a variable first but then later sanitized?

Comment: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Wrong.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Shell double-quotes requires a double escaping.

Exemple `echo "\$"` will print '$'
But `echo "\\$"` will print '\$'

And '$' is the end of line regex marker and is the shell variable prefix.
The following patterns will work fines

```
egrep "\\\$_GET|\\\$_POST" -r -i MyFolder > dangerousUse.txt
egrep "[$]_GET|[$]_POST" -r -i MyFolder > dangerousUse.txt
egrep '\$_GET|\$_POST' -r -i MyFolder > dangerousUse.txt
```

The latest is the simpler because shell does not perform variable interpolation inside single-quote and there is no escaping.

Probably one method to insure that you check all you input is to define a `sanitized_GET` and a `sanitized_POST` function which perform all the stuff.

Comment: Hi VGE, I thought about creating a `sanitize_Input` function, but if I know that I want an integer, intval will be much better than `mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($input))` which I have to use for Strings. I think its faster and its easier to see, that the variable is an int from this point of the code. By the way, why should I define two seperate functions for GET and POST?

Comment: It is up to you. There is probably thousands ways to implement this. It depends if performance is really important in your case. I do not use php for years (I rather prefer working with django-python), but at this time I usually used $_REQUEST, so it is another solution.

Comment: Why do you prefer django? Has $_REQUEST any advantages / disadvantages compared with $_GET and $_POST or is it only another way to access submitted data?

Comment: I have now found what I was searching vor: `egrep -v`, it inverts my matches.

Comment: $_REQUEST is an easy way to gather _GET and _POST. For django look at this and make your choice http://stackoverflow.com/questions/91846/rails-or-django-or-something-else .

Answer (score 0):

The `\$` in your example is probably interpreted by your shell and a un-escaped `$` is passed to `grep`, since the shell expands variables starting with `$`.  Try using single quotes or shell-escape the `\$` instead:

```
egrep '\$_GET|\$_POST'
egrep "\\\$_GET|\\\$_POST"
```

Additionally, you might want to use the `-H` and `-n` options to output the matching file and line number, respectively.  This way you can easily locate the dangerous usage locations.

You can filter out "good" matches from your "dangerousUse.txt" using grep, too, using the `-v` (revert) switch:

```
egrep -H -n '\$_GET|\$_POST' -r -i MyFolder | egrep -v 'mysql_real_escape_string|intval|isset|<...>' > dangerousUse.txt
```

Comment: Are you sure `egrep "\\$_GET|\\$_POST"` that $_GET will not be expanded by an empty string ?

Comment: I do not know who has said about shell something like: "there is never enough backslash"